# Ansible config is ignored

Tags: ansible

In my ansible config file I added some non default values:

```
log_path=./ansible_log.txt

# (boolean) Normally ``ansible-playbook`` will print a header for each task that is run. These headers will contain the name: field from the task if you specified one. If you didn't then ``ansible-playbook`` uses the task's action to help you tell which task is presently running. Sometimes you run many of the same action and so you want more information about the task to differentiate it from others of the same action. If you set this variable to True in the config then ``ansible-playbook`` will also include the task's arguments in the header.
# This setting defaults to False because there is a chance that you have sensitive values in your parameters and you do not want those to be printed.
# If you set this to True you should be sure that you have secured your environment's stdout (no one can shoulder surf your screen and you aren't saving stdout to an insecure file) or made sure that all of your playbooks explicitly added the ``no_log: True`` parameter to tasks which have sensitive values See How do I keep secret data in my playbook? for more information.
display_args_to_stdout=True

# (boolean) Set this to "False" if you want to avoid host key checking by the underlying tools Ansible uses to connect to the host
host_key_checking=False


# (string) Set the main callback used to display Ansible output. You can only have one at a time.
# You can have many other callbacks, but just one can be in charge of stdout.
# See :ref:`callback_plugins` for a list of available options.
;stdout_callback=default

callbacks_enabled=ansible.posix.profile_tasks, ansible.posix.timer
```

When I run `ansible --version` in the same directory as where I execute my ansible playbooks I get:

> ansible [core 2.15.3]
> config file = /home/my_name/repos/some_repo/dev/ansible.cfg

When I use `cat /home/my_name/repos/some_repo/dev/ansible.cfg` to see the contents of the config file, I can verify that the config has the content as mentioned above.

So the ansible `--version` reports the expected ansible.cfg file, the file contains the expected settings, but the settings seem to be ignored, I do not see the extra output from the callback values, and also no logging is generated.

How can I make sure the ansible.cfg values are not ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if thats the whole config file you forgot `[defaults]` header.

`ansible-config` command can help you to check your configurations.

in general ansible read configurations in order from:
env variable: ANSIBLE_CONFIG
paths:

- ${PWD}/ansible.cfg
- ${HOME}/.ansible.cfg
- /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg

for instance to check which file will be used by ansible if you run any command in your current directory you'd use `ansible-config view`. it will show content of files which will be used.

or to check all configurations which are set you can use `ansible-config dump` and check what is set for You.

example:

```
Shell > mkdir /tmp/testing-config

Shell > cd /tmp/testing-config

Shell > ansible-config view
ERROR! Invalid or no config file was supplied

Shell > ansible-config dump | grep -iE 'log_path|args_to_stdout|host_key_checking|callbacks_enabled'
CALLBACKS_ENABLED(default) = []
DEFAULT_LOG_PATH(default) = None
DISPLAY_ARGS_TO_STDOUT(default) = False
HOST_KEY_CHECKING(default) = True

Shell > cat << 'E' > ansible.cfg
[defaults]
log_path=./ansible_log.txt
display_args_to_stdout=True
host_key_checking=False
callbacks_enabled=ansible.posix.profile_tasks, ansible.posix.timer
> E

Shell > ansible-config view
[defaults]
log_path=./ansible_log.txt
display_args_to_stdout=True
host_key_checking=False
callbacks_enabled=ansible.posix.profile_tasks, ansible.posix.timer

Shell > ansible-config dump | grep -iE 'log_path|args_to_stdout|host_key_checking|callbacks_enabled'
CALLBACKS_ENABLED(/tmp/testing-config/ansible.cfg) = ['ansible.posix.profile_tasks', 'ansible.posix.timer']
DEFAULT_LOG_PATH(/tmp/testing-config/ansible.cfg) = /tmp/testing-config/ansible_log.txt
DISPLAY_ARGS_TO_STDOUT(/tmp/testing-config/ansible.cfg) = True
HOST_KEY_CHECKING(/tmp/testing-config/ansible.cfg) = False

Shell > ls
ansible.cfg  ansible_log.txt

Shell > a -c local -m command -a 'whoami' localhost
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
localhost | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
yaser

Shell > cat ansible_log.txt
2024-02-14 14:24:38,411 p=33536 u=yaser n=ansible | [WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available

2024-02-14 14:24:38,659 p=33536 u=yaser n=ansible | localhost | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
yaser
```

Comment: Indeed I did not add the [defaults], that fixed it, thanks. Not really forgot, but the docs were not clear to me about needing it.

Answer (score -1):

I added the content exactly as I posted in the question at the bottom of the file.
The variables should be in the correct ini bracket e.g. [defaults].

After adding it in the correct bracket instead of at the bottom at the file it worked.